# How to remove characters from a string to get the desired format?

Tags: c#

I have a string representation exactly like 'ComputerName -- IPAddress'; i.e:

> 'samarena -- 192.168.1.97'

. I want to get only the 'ComputerName' part from the actual representation by removing other characters. I'm actually quite beginner in using `string.FormatMethods()` .

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string test = "samarena -- 192.168.1.97";
var result = test.Split(new string[] { "--" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].Trim();
```

Result will equal `samarena`

Answer (score 0):

you could split the string on ' -- ' and then use the first part

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
var yourString = "samarena -- 192.168.1.97";
var indexOfDash = yourString.IndexOf("-");
var yourComputerName = yourString.SubString(0, indexOfDash).Trim();
```

But the other answers using Trim are better :)

This'd be the totally imperative way.

Answer (score 0):

If You are sure there is always a substring " -- " after the part You want, You can do this

```
myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf(" -- "))
```

Or use a shorter part of " -- ".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char [] chars = {'-'};
string test = "samarena -- 192.168.1.97";

//computerName array will have the Computer Name at the very first index (it is a zero based index    
string[] computerName = test.Split(chars,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//computerName[0] is your computerName
```